# "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found" after one call || Scotchbox || Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using Laravel 5.2 on a Scotchbox server.

Everything with the DB works as it should, but only for one call, or only a few seconds.

I can consult the "phpmyadmin" page, but also only once or twice.
After a few second even this page gives me a 404 error.

I have to restart my scotchbox everytime to do something with the DB.

Laravel doesn't say it can't connect to the DB but says it can't find the table I defined in it:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'scotchbox.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`userId` = 4 limit 1)

And when I want to connect to phpmyadmin again after it got stuck Laravel says:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use other Vagrant box? For example homestead?

Comment: No, I'm working on this for school, never used another vagrant box. But I'll try

Comment: [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) is specifically made to run Laravel apps, so it's the recommended solution for Laravel development.

Comment: Recommended box for Laravel is Homestead. I've never used Scotchbox but looking at what is hapenning it might be a bug or other issue with this box, so you should try to install Homstead box first to make sure this issue is also present on this box